# Pass 1d texture into fragment shader - all zeroes?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, fragment-shader

I'm trying to pass an array of ints into the fragment shader by using a 1D texture. Although the code compiles and runs, when I look at the texture values in the shader, they are all zero!

This is the C++ code I have after following a number of tutorials:

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 5); // use the 5th since first 4 may be taken
glBindTexture  (GL_TEXTURE_1D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, myVec.size(), 0, 
                               GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, &myVec[0]);

GLint textureLoc =  glGetUniformLocation( program, "myTexture" );
glUniform1i(textureLoc, 5);
```

And this how I try and access the texture in the shader:

```
uniform sampler1D myTexture; 
int dat = int(texture1D(myTexture, 0.0).r); // 0.0 is just an example 
if (dat == 0) { // always true!
```

I'm sure this is some trivial error on my part, but I just can't figure it out. I'm unfortunately constrained to using GLSL 1.20, so this syntax may seem outdated to some.

**So why are the texture values in the shader always zero?**

**EDIT:**

If I replace the int's with floats, I still have a problem:

```
std::vector <float> temp; 
// fill temp...
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_R32F, temp.size(), 0, GL_R32F, GL_FLOAT, &temp[0]);
// ...
glUniform1f(textureLoc, 5);
```

This time, just reading from the `sampler` seems to mess up the other textures..

Comment: I think the result is normalized to [0,1] float for int formats texture fetches. Try a `isampler1D` sampler

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - `isampler1D` won't compile,  and `GL_R16I` and  `GL_R32I` don't change anything.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - It doesn't seem to work with floats either - I've added the code to the question. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: See my answer, and do not use a floating-point texture. Use a regular fixed-point (unsigned normalized is the technical term) texture. So something like `glTexImage1D (GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_R8, myVec.size (), GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &myVec [0]);`. You will need to make adjustments to the size and type and the GLSL shader if you need to store more than 256 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, `GL_RED_INTEGER` is wrong for the internal format. I would use `GL_R32I` (32-bit signed integer) instead, you could also use `GL_R8I` or `GL_R16I` depending on your actual storage requirements - smaller types are generally better. Also, do not use a `sampler1D` for an integer texture, use `isampler1D`.

Since OpenGL ES does not support data type conversion when you use a pixel transfer function (e.g. `glTexture2D (...)`), you can usually find the optimal combination of format, internal format and type in a table if you look through the [OpenGL ES docs](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml).

---

You cannot use integer textures in OpenGL 2.1, if we are back to the same problem you were having yesterday with UBOs. If you cannot get a core profile context on OS X, you are limited to GLSL 1.2 (OpenGL 2.1). The constants for `GL_R32I`, `GL_RED_INTEGER`, etc. will be defined, but they should create `GL_INVALID_ENUM` errors at runtime in OS X's OpenGL 2.1 implementation.

That is not to say you cannot pack an integer value into a standard fixed-point texture and get an integer value back out in a shader. If you use an 8-bit per component format (e.g. `GL_R8`) you can store values in the range **0** - **255**. In your shader, after you do a texture lookup (I would use `GL_NEAREST` for the texture filter, filtering will really mess things up) you can multiply the floating-point result by **255.0** and cast to `int`. It is far from perfect, but we got along fine without integer textures for many years.

#### Here is a modification to your shader that does exactly that:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler1D myTexture;
int dat = (int)(texture1D (myTexture, (idx + 0.5)/(float)textureWidth).r * 255.0);
if (dat == 0) { // not always true!
```

<sub>Assumes `GL_R8` for the internal format, use `65535.0` for `GL_R16`</sub>

Comment: `texelFetch` won't compile, and `float dat = texture1D(myTexture, 0.0).r * 65535.0;` always gives zero as well :(

Comment: @Nathaniel which `version` directive are you using?

Comment: @Nathaniel: Yeah, I forgot `texelFetch (...)` is not in GLSL 1.20 for a minute there. I will have an updated answer shortly, you are going to have to do some math to compute the floating-point texture coordinate from your integer index. This math will require you to know the dimensions of your texture in the shader. See my comment about the texture filter - it needs to be `GL_NEAREST` for this sort of thing to work.

Comment: the result is still always zero - I'm tearing my hair out :(

Comment: @Nathaniel: Can you show the call you used to supply data to your 1D texture? I think you are using invalid enums, you were in the last edit to your question anyway (`format` should be **GL_RED** in that case - sized formats like **GL_R32F** are only for `internalFormat`).

Comment: Using this `glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_R8, (temp).size(), 0, GL_R8, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &(temp)[0]);` as you suggested.

Comment: @Nathaniel: That is not actually what I suggested, the second instance of **GL_R8** needs to be **GL_RED**. Only the first **GL_R8** (`internalFormat`) and **GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE** (`type`) constants will need to be changed if you decide to use a larger data type for your texture, **GL_RED** will always be the correct value to use for `format`. If you make a habit of calling `glGetError (...)` after attempting these changes, that might help a lot. The code you just mentioned, for instance, should generate **GL_INVALID_ENUM**